# how does html dom head and body work?

Tags: html, css

Why does the string hello has background color yellow? Why isn't it black?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head style="background-color:black">
  <title>Check123!</title>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
</head>

<body style="background-color:yellow">
  <h1>World!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Your HTML is wrong: the `<head>` element should contain a metadata of document (see [specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-head-element) for details). The `<h1>` should be placed within `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

> **Default CSS Settings**
>   Most browsers will display the  element with the following default values:
>   `head { 
>       display: none;
>    }`

You should put the page's metadata in the head, so there is usually no need to display it.

You get the color from the parent container of your `<h1>` title, which is `<body>`.

Answer (score 0):

What ever the html elements you are creating should come inside body tag only. head is where to give information about the title of the page and where the stylesheet and scripts files exist.i thing you got confused with header and head.
header is a html5 tag that comes inside the body tag

Answer (score 0):

H1 is not in the header. H1 should be written in body. If you do not do this, the browser itself corrects your mistake and transfers it to the body.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_head.asp

The `<head>` element is a container for metadata (data about data) and is placed between the `<html>` tag and the `<body>` tag.

HTML metadata is data about the HTML document. Metadata is not displayed.

Metadata typically define the document title, character set, styles, links, scripts, and other meta information.

The following tags describe metadata: `<title>`, `<style>`, `<meta>`, `<link>`, `<script>`, and `<base>`.

Answer (score 0):

Everything you want visible should be in the `<body>` tag. Your `h1` should be inside of a `header` tag inside your `body`. The `head` tag is reserved for `meta` tags and linking stylesheets.

In your case, it should be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <header style="background-color:black">
      <h1>Check123!</h1>
      <h2>Hello</h2>
    </header>
    <article style="background-color:yellow">
      <h3>World!</h3>
    </article>
  </body>
```